# Waking up from suspend makes most things turn black when using Ubuntu 21.10 with Wayland

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, wayland, 21.10

Whenever my computer wakes up from suspend when it is using Wayland, all the icons in the dock disappear, the desktop background goes black, and the bar at the top of the screen with the time goes completely black.

Also, it sometimes duplicates my mouse if I move it, leaving a trail of duplicate mouse pointers, kind of similar to the old Windows XP error message glitch where it would duplicate the error message when you dragged it, happens with everything that moves (This normally only affects one monitor at a time, but can occur on all of them at once.)

`ALT`+`TAB` also stops working.

Here are a couple of pictures of what it looks like when it wakes from suspend:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The only way I have found so far to fix this, is to reboot, or sometimes logging out and back in (Logging out sometimes does not work, and the system still acts strangely)

Is there any way to stop this from happening every time it wakes from suspend?

System Details:

Processor: Intel Core i5-6600K

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660/PCIe/SSE2

Graphics Driver: NVIDIA metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)

OS Name: Ubuntu 21.10

GNOME Version: 40.4.0

Windowing System: Wayland

Comment: I have same issue in 21.10 and 22.04